# How many functions under the given conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{x,y,z,w\}$.

a) How many functions $f$ are there such that $f : B → A$ and $f(x) = 2$?
I know the number of functions from $B$ to $A$ is $3^4$.

b) How many functions $f$ are there such that $f : A → B$ and $|f(A)| = 2$?
The number of functions mapping $A$ to $B$ is $4^3$.

Is there a general formula to solve these questions?

Comment: a) since $f(x)$ is fixed how many functions from $\{y,z,w\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ ?

Comment: If you would like a more complete answer, please edit your question to show your attempts and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general formula, yes. Without any restrictions, there are $|B|^{|A|}$ functions from $A$ to $B$, since each of the $|A|$ elements in $A$ can be mapped to each of the $|B|$ elements in $B$.

Once you start putting restrictions on the functions, you'll likely have to find a custom solution, although some of the thinking will remain the same. For example, for functions from $B$ to $A$ with the  restriction that $f(x)=2$ you basically fix the function value for $1$ of the elements of $B$, but since you still have total freedom for all others, you'd get that there are $|A|^{|B|-1}$ such functions.

Now, can you try and do the second question using this kind of thinking?

Comment: Do I find the answer using the Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind, or is there another way?

Comment: @N.Summer That could work sure!

Comment: Okay, Thanks! Is that the only way to solve it though?

Comment: @N.Summer I doubt it is ... but nothing comes to my mind.  So ... what is your eventual answer for b)?

Comment: Ok. So would the formula (4 nCr 2) (2! S(3,2)) be correct for b? Which I believe would be 18?

Comment: @N.Summer ... not sure what that $2!$ is doing there, but yes, you need to choose 2 out of 4 (which is 6) and multiply by S(3,2) (which is 3), so that's indeed 18

Comment: The factor of $2!$ is necessary since we must choose which of the two elements in the range is the image of two elements in the domain.  Therefore, there are $36$ functions $f: A \to B$ such that $|f(A)| = 2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Quite!  Yes, my mistake, the 2! should indee be there, and so it's 36, not 18. Thanks!!